# set-up error on compile react native "gradle"

Tags: javascript, android, gradle, react-native

Hey im trying to add i18 plugin to react native project and I got this problem   that shows 2 files 1 have error but I don't know what can be wrong there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the following line in the wrong file :

```
compile project(':react-native-i18n')
```

You've added it to `android/build.gradle` instead of `android/app/build.gradle`